# DFA complement: DFA on $\{a,b\}$ that accepts string where the numbers of $a$s not multiple of n

Tags: finite-automata

I'm trying to understand how to create a DFA on the language $\{a,b\}$ that accepts strings where the number of $a$s is **not** a multiple of n.

Creating a DFA with no. of $a$s divisible by $n$ is easy. One simply makes $n$ states such that the string ends into the accept state per every $n$ of e.g. $a$s.

I've figured out that the set of "natural numbers not divisible by $n$" can be found by considering all $k$ such that $k=nm+j$, $0≤j<n$.

I haven't been able to figure out how to translate this to a DFA. It's implicative that "not divisible" is a complement of "divisible".

Comment: So you know how to build a DFA for $L_n = \{x \in \{a,b\}^*: \#_a(x) \in n \mathbb{N} \}$, and what you're looking for is a DFA for $\bar L_n$. There's a simple algorithm for taking the complement of a language accepted by a DFA, and that algorithm only works because for every word in $\Sigma^*$, there is exactly one run through the DFA using that word.

Answer (score 1):

What about your "divisible" automaton and changing the accept states?

Comment: Seems to work out. But I'm not sure what the "logic" is here. It reminds vaguely of the mathematical formulation. Like one "starts" with the remainder e.g. one $a$ and after that's read "switches" to reading $n$ $a$s in every cycle so that it accepts only no. of $a$s so that the "remainder" is always one (that is, it accepts strings with $a$+(number of $a$s read before the first accept).

Comment: Actually, following Anton's comment. Taking the complement of the "divisible by $n$" automaton does seem to exactly allow for the remainders $j$ between $0≤j<n$.

Answer (score 1):

Build a DFA $A$ accepting strings with the number of $a$s divisible by $n$: $$A = (Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F).$$

Now you want to make a DFA accepting the complement of the language of A: $C(L(A)) = \Sigma^*-L(A)$.

To do that take the complement of the final states of the original DFA:
$$A' = (Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F'),$$
where $F' = Q-F$

**Update**

Let's prove $L(A') = C(L(A))$:

1) If $s \in L(A')$ then $\hat{\delta}(q_0,s) \in F'$, where $\hat{\delta}$ is the extended transition function. Since $F' = Q-F$, it means that $\hat{\delta}(q_0,s) \not \in F$, hence $s \not \in L(A)$, thus $s \in C(L(A))$.

2) If $s \in C(L(A))$, then $s \not \in L(A)$, so $\hat{\delta}(q_0,s) \not \in F$. Therefore $\hat{\delta}(q_0,s) \in F'$. But it means $s \in L(A')$.

That's pretty much all.

Comment: What does it mean to "complement the final states"? In the graphical sense of the DFA? Also is there a proof for why does this work?

Comment: To take the complement of the final states means to "invert" states: make non-final final and vice versa.

Comment: Not sure that there is a proof of this construction that can be easily found -- it looks more like an exercise for an automata course.

Comment: I meant a proof that taking the complement of final states of a DFA gives a DFA that accepts the complement of the language. If this is not a general property, then I think the answer could be motivated to be more specific to this question. Also, DFAs should be mathematical provable?

Comment: Me too. The idea is simple: new DFA doesn't accept the strings it previously accepted, and accepts the strings it used to discard. This is essentially what complement is.

Comment: I updated the post with a proof.